# Processing of two or more same JMS messages concurrently from a single queue

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-jms

Consider below scenario:

```
Application - MessageReaderApplication (Spring Boot Application)
Deployed in - PaaS_node_1 and PaaS_node_2 
Queue Manager - QM
Queue - QM_QUEUE
Concurrency - 2
```

MessageReaderApplication reads messages from QM_QUEUE and processes them according to **client_number** in the message (**client_number** is a unique attribute of the message). The application behaves well for two independent messages (different **client_number**) as the processing of one message is independent of others.

The problem comes when the messages come for the same client (same ***client_number***) twice at the same time in the queue. In this case, the desirable action is to process the first message prior to the second one. But here we cannot predict the execution order of the messages. Suppose PaaS_node_1 picked the first message and started processing on it meanwhile the second message picked by PaaS_node_2 and finished processing before processing the first message by PaaS_node_1.

How can we achieve this kind of concurrency control in JMS messaging?

Answer (score 0):

You either need a separate queue for each clientId or a separate listener for each client id (using a message selector to only get those messages).

Comment: Separating queue for each client id is not possible as its part of the same message. I have searched more on this. One solution is using Hazelcast. Any thoughts on this?